# How to handle or display custom page not found (404 page) in Spring Boot and JSP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, custom-error-pages

I am working on spring boot application and JSP. I want to display custom styled 404 error page when a user hits some different URLs like https://www.example.com/about/random-unauthorized-url
so, https://www.example.com/about is a valid URL but https://www.example.com/about/random-unauthorized-url is not a valid URL. So I want when this thing happens, 404 page should get displayed instead of redirection on home page. Current scenario is when I supply some invalid URLs with domain name, it gets redirected to index or home page, which I don't want. So I tried using **some properties in application.yml file as below**:

```
server:
  port: 1207
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

**Below is custom security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(WebUrl.index).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(WebUrl.about).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(WebUrl.pageNotFound).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
        
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthenticatedRequestHandler());
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthenticatedRequestHandler()); 
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendRedirect("/login");
    }
    
    @Bean
    UnauthenticatedRequestHandler unauthenticatedRequestHandler() {
        return new UnauthenticatedRequestHandler();
    }
}
```

**This is to handle unauthenticated requests**

```
public class UnauthenticatedRequestHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Request coming here....!!! "+request.getServletPath());
       if(request.getServletPath().startsWith("/admin/")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/admin/login");
        }else {
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

**and created custom error handling controller also**

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController{

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return WebUrl.pageNotFound;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value= {WebUrl.pageNotFound},method= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        if(status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());
            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                modelAndView = new ModelAndView(WebUrl.pageNotFound);
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**Below is the structure of view:**

```
src/main/webapp/views/page-not-found.jsp
```

Unfortunately, above solutions did not worked for me or maybe I mixed things. **Please help me on this to solve.**

Comment: To confirm: what is value of WebURL.pageNotFound property this should match the getErrorPath so your redirect return "/page-not-found" should be WebURL.pageNotFound

Comment: value of WebUrl.pageNotFound is "/page-not-found". This is the url for cutom 404 error page

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Boot documentation provides a section talking about [custom error pages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling.error-pages). It states:

> If you want to display a custom HTML error page for a given status code,
> you can add a file to an /error directory. Error pages can either be static
> HTML (that is, added under any of the static resource directories) or be
> built by using templates. The name of the file should be the exact status
> code or a series mask.
>
> For example, to map `404` to a static HTML file, your directory structure
> would be as follows:

```
src/
 +- main/
     +- java/
     |   + <source code>
     +- resources/
         +- public/
             +- error/
             |   +- 404.html
             +- <other public assets>
```

> To map all `5xx` errors by using a FreeMarker template, your directory
> structure would be as follows:

```
src/
 +- main/
     +- java/
     |   + <source code>
     +- resources/
         +- templates/
             +- error/
             |   +- 5xx.ftlh
             +- <other templates>
```

It provides further advice about using `ErrorViewResolver`, `@ExceptionHandler`s or `@ControllerAdvice`, but for your use case I think providing a custom `404.jsp` file could do the trick.

In fact, I must say sorry, because I realized you are possibly not using Spring in this way, but with a `webapp` related structure.

If that is the case, one direct approach you could follow is the aforementioned based on `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ControllerAdvice`. Please, try creating a custom exception handler similar to this:

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleNoHandlerFoundException (NoHandlerFoundException e) {
        // Consider logging the error
        return new ModelAndView("page-not-found.jsp");
    }

}
```

For this code to work properly, you need to configure Spring to raise [`NoHandlerFoundException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/NoHandlerFoundException.html) when no handler is found.

You can do this for example by setting the configuration property [spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found) to `true`:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know whether it worked or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are welcome @Rakhi. The solution proposed should fit most use cases, I hope it helps in yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing the spring ErrorController ?
Using this, you can have specific error pages for specific response status codes like '403' and '404'.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I have created custom error handler implements ErrorController.

Comment: oh, I missed that, sorry, where are my glasses ?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Write @RequestMapping("/error") for handleError method.

Look at below code:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //Log here !!!
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());

            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "500";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()) {
                return "403";
            }
        }

        return "generalError";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

and look at 404.html file location in project structure.

[image]